# Using grep/gsub To Find First Colon Only

Tags: r, regex

I have a long file which is written as ONLY one column.
This column contains gene names followed by a colon (:) then by the name of a microRNA fragment. 
Unfortunately, the microRNA name **MAY ALSO** contain a colon (:).

I want to replace **ONLY** the **first colon** with a tab (\t) and then write.table to produce two columns in R.

*Here is a representative sample of one gene name with multiple microRNAs:*

```
CHD5:miR-329/362-3p:2
CHD5:miR-329/362-3p:1
CHD5:miR-30a/30a-5p/30b/30b-5p/30cde/384-5p
CHD5:miR-15/16/195/424/497
CHD5:miR-26ab/1297
CHD5:miR-17-5p/20/93.mr/106/519.d
CHD5:miR-130/301
CHD5:miR-19
CHD5:miR-204/211
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly more complete example if you have your 'inFile' and want 'outFile'...

```
lines <- readLines('inFile')
lines <- sub(':', '\t', x)
writeLines(lines, 'outFile')
```

Comment: Actually this is quite elegant too! I like it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use `sub` instead of `gsub`?

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is your column or vector:

```
sub(":", "\t", x)
```

See `?sub`, which says

> ‘sub’ and ‘gsub’ perform replacement of the first and all matches
>       respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If you are all right with using `sed`, you can do the following (assuming your data is in a file named `data.txt`).

```
sed 's/\([^:]\):/\1 /' data.txt
```

That space after the `\1` is really a tab. To insert it in my shell, I needed to do Ctrl-v, <tab>.

Here's my result after running the command:

```
CHD5    miR-329/362-3p:2
CHD5    miR-329/362-3p:1
CHD5    miR-30a/30a-5p/30b/30b-5p/30cde/384-5p
CHD5    miR-15/16/195/424/497
CHD5    miR-26ab/1297
CHD5    miR-17-5p/20/93.mr/106/519.d
CHD5    miR-130/301
CHD5    miR-19
CHD5    miR-204/211
```

Comment: I Used:      
sed 's/\([^:]\):/\1 /' <old.txt >new.txt

Comment: Did that work for you without escaping the parentheses? I have to replace `(` and `)` with `\(` and `\)`, respectively, for the command to work.

Comment: BEST: 's/\([^:]\):/\1"\t"/' <old_data.txt >now_two_cols.txt

Comment: As you may have seen I added the "\t" so that I can use excel and R more easily, but YES it worked, Thanks David